# How to check if the table has a class or not using hasClass function of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem on the onclick function of table b the function does not determine if table A has a class of **selected_upsize** or not

Scenario:
Table B has a list of item and also in table A. 
now when I click one of the items in Table B, the on click function will do the condition if table A has a class of selected_upsize or not, To make the scenario short.

if the table **A** has a class of (selected_upsize) then it will alert something, else the item of that I clicked in table B will append on table A.

**I have here my output**
[image: Output]

I have here my function to my Onclick function

```
     $(".customer_edit_table_chaining_condiments").on('click',function(e){

                        //this is the item of table B that will append if the table A has no class
                        var customer_edit_condimentsScreenNameClicked = $(this).closest('tr').find('.customer_edit_condimentsScreenNameClicked').text();
                        var customer_edit_condimentsScreenPriced = $(this).closest('tr').find('.customer_edit_condimentsScreenPriced').text();

                       $(".customer_edit_table_chaining_condiments").on('click',function(e){

        //this is the item of table B that will append if the table A has no class
        var customer_edit_condimentsScreenNameClicked = $(this).closest('tr').find('.customer_edit_condimentsScreenNameClicked').text();
        var customer_edit_condimentsScreenPriced = $(this).closest('tr').find('.customer_edit_condimentsScreenPriced').text();

       if($('#noun_chaining_order').find('tr.selected_upsize').length){    

            alert('You can"t upsize the item');
       }else{                                        
            $('table#noun_chaining_order').append('<tr class="" id="append_imaginary_upsize_condiments"><td contenteditable="true">-</td><td>'+customer_edit_condimentsScreenNameClicked+'</td><td>'+customer_edit_condimentsScreenPriced+'</td></tr>');
            $('tr#append_imaginary_upsize_condiments').addClass('selected_upsize');

       }
})
```

My Html Table A

```
<table class="table table-hover upsize_check" id="noun_chaining_order" style="border:none;">
<thead>
    <tr style="font-size: 15px;  color:white;">
        <th scope="col">Qty</th>
        <th scope="col">Condiments</th>
        <th scope="col">Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody style="font-size:14px; color:white;" class="tbody_noun_chaining_order">                  

</tbody>
```

Table B

```
<table  class="table table-striped table-bordered " id="customer_table_update_chain_order" style="width:100%">
<div class="content-noun" style="text-align: center;">
<thead>
    <tr style="background: linear-gradient(-20deg, #00e4d0, #5983e8); color:white;" >
        <th>Condiment Screen Name</th>
         <th>Condiment Price</th>
         <th>Condiment Image</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    </div>
<tbody>

</tbody>
```

Comment: The else part will never be called, as the class will always have the 'selected_upsize' class
Please try adding another class name to the element which might or might not have the selected_upsize class, and then find your element using this new class.

Comment: hi kumar what do you mean for that? can you do more elaborate?

Comment: Because you find all element with 'selected_upsize' class

Comment: You can use the new class in the find method here... 
`$('table#noun_chaining_order').find('.new_class').each(function(){`

Comment: can you give some example, thanks kumar

Comment: I have added comments in CAPS  to help you understand better. Hope this helps...

Comment: Why are you looping over when the there is only one table(table A)?. Why this loop `$('table#noun_chaining_order').find('.selected_upsize').each(function()...`

Comment: I just wan't to check each table row if has a class of selected_upsize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.
If my understanding is correct this should work.

```
$(".customer_edit_table_chaining_condiments").on('click',function(e){

        //this is the item of table B that will append if the table A has no class
        var customer_edit_condimentsScreenNameClicked = $(this).closest('tr').find('.customer_edit_condimentsScreenNameClicked').text();
        var customer_edit_condimentsScreenPriced = $(this).closest('tr').find('.customer_edit_condimentsScreenPriced').text();

       if($('#noun_chaining_order').find('tr.selected_upsize').length){    

            alert('You can"t upsize the item');
       }else{                                        
            $('table#noun_chaining_order').append('<tr class="" id="append_imaginary_upsize_condiments"><td contenteditable="true">-</td><td>'+customer_edit_condimentsScreenNameClicked+'</td><td>'+customer_edit_condimentsScreenPriced+'</td></tr>');
            $('tr#append_imaginary_upsize_condiments').addClass('selected_upsize');

       }
})
```

Comment: Mark this as an answer so it would be helpful for future readers. :)

Comment: You might wanna see the SO sections. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks again techie

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".customer_edit_table_chaining_condiments").on('click',function(e){

    //this is the item of table B that will append if the table A has no class
    var customer_edit_condimentsScreenNameClicked = $(this).closest('tr').find('.customer_edit_condimentsScreenNameClicked').text();
    var customer_edit_condimentsScreenPriced = $(this).closest('tr').find('.customer_edit_condimentsScreenPriced').text();

    //here will check if table A has selected upsize or not

    //THE BELOw LINE WILL RETURN ALL THE ELEMENTS WITH SELECTED_UPSIZE CLASS IF WE HAVE .SELECTED_UPSIZE IN THE FIND METHOD, THUS THE BELOW LINE WILL ALWAYS BE TRUE
    $('table#noun_chaining_order').find('.upsize_check').each(function(){
    //INSTEAD IF YOU SEARCH FOR THE ELEMENTS WITH A DIFFERENT CLASS as in the above line of code, THAT MIGHT OR MIGHT NOT HAVE THE SELECTED_UPSIZE CLASS WITH IT, THEREFORE MAKING THE BELOW STATEMENTS LEGAL
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected_upsize')) {

            alert('You can"t upsize the item');
        }
        else
        {
            $('table#noun_chaining_order').append('<tr class="" id="append_imaginary_upsize_condiments"><td contenteditable="true">-</td><td>'+customer_edit_condimentsScreenNameClicked+'</td><td>'+customer_edit_condimentsScreenPriced+'</td></tr>');
            $('tr#append_imaginary_upsize_condiments').addClass('selected_upsize');
        }

    });

});
```

ADDING THE SOLUTION BELOW....

HTML

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="noun_chaining_order" style="border:none;">
<thead>
    <tr style="font-size: 15px;  color:white;">
        <th scope="col">Qty</th>
        <th scope="col">Condiments</th>
        <th scope="col">Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody style="font-size:14px; color:white;" class="tbody_noun_chaining_order">                  
</tbody>

<table  class="table table-striped table-bordered " id="customer_table_update_chain_order" style="width:100%">
    <div class="content-noun" style="text-align: center;">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background: linear-gradient(-20deg, #00e4d0, #5983e8); color:white;" >
             <th>Condiment Screen Name</th>
             <th>Condiment Price</th>
             <th>Condiment Image</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    </div>
<tbody>

</tbody>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("#customer_table_update_chain_order tbody tr").on('click',function(e){

                //this is the item of table B that will append if the table A has no class
                var customer_edit_condimentsScreenNameClicked = $(this).find('.customer_edit_condimentsScreenNameClicked').text();
                var customer_edit_condimentsScreenPriced = $(this).find('.customer_edit_condimentsScreenPriced').text();

                //here will check if table A has selected upsize or not
                        $('table#noun_chaining_order tbody tr').each(function(){
                    if ($(this).hasClass('selected_upsize')) {

                    sameRow = true;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    sameRow =false;
                    $('table#noun_chaining_order').append('<tr class="" id="append_imaginary_upsize_condiments"><td contenteditable="true">-</td><td>'+customer_edit_condimentsScreenNameClicked+'</td><td>'+customer_edit_condimentsScreenPriced+'</td></tr>');
                    $('tr#append_imaginary_upsize_condiments').addClass('selected_upsize');
                  }

                    });


            if(sameRow){
                alert('You can"t upsize the item');
            }

              });
```

Comment: I have added the .each function twice for the explanation, Please remove one

Comment: I have revised the code, please add the upsize_check class in your HTML as well

Comment: could you please add your HTML here as well

Comment: @DevGe I have added the solution, Please have a look

Comment: Hi Kumar why the append multiply? every click 2 appended in my table

Comment: Initially when TABLE A is empty, it will not have any rows, thus we will have to append the clicked value in TABLE A. You can remove the length check `if condition` if you will never have TABLE A Empty

Comment: I have removed the extra if condition. Please have a look

Comment: hi kumar, when i click on table B, the item is appending multiple times

Comment: Thanks kumar for the help also